# Read float from input stream without trailing "E"

Tags: c++, iostream

I do the following:

```
float f;
cin >> f;
```

On the string:

```
0.123W
```

Number 0.123 will be properly read to `f`, and stream reading will be stopped on 'W'. But if we enter:

```
0.123E
```

operation will fail and cin.fail() will return true. Probably the trailing 'E' will be treated as part of scientific notation.

I've tried `cin.unsetf(std::ios::scientific);` with no success.

Is there any possibility to disable treating character 'E' specially?

Comment: Have you tried std::cin.ignore ?

Comment: My intention is to read a floating point number successfully and leave 'E' character for further reading. What is point of using ignore here?

Comment: At least on Mac OS X, the C language standard I/O facilities accept the `0.123E` notation as being a floating point number 0.123 followed by an unused letter E.  That suggests that one option is to use that, though it is not nice given that you're working in C++. Working in C++ (`g++` 4.8.2), I get the error.  This suggests that the C++ standard requires the error, unlike the C standard — though from a C programmer's perspective, that seems like broken behaviour — both `0.123E` and `0.123E-` should be OK, stopping at the E.

Comment: Nitpick: it's not a *leading*, it's a *trailing* `e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to parse it your self. Here is some code:

```
// Note: Requires C++11
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

float string_to_float (const string& str)
{
    size_t pos;
    float value = stof (str, &pos);
    // Check if whole string is used. Only allow extra chars if isblank()
    if (pos != str.length()) {
        if (not all_of (str.cbegin()+pos, str.cend(), isblank))
            throw invalid_argument ("string_to_float: extra characters");
    }
    return value;
}
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
string str;
if (cin >> str) {
    float val = string_to_float (str);
    cout << "Got " << val << "\n";
} else cerr << "cin error!\n"; // or eof?
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to read the value as a string, and parse it yourself.