# How does c++ interpret 6e(or any number with e) as an input?

Tags: c++

When running this code and entering 6e or any other digit with e, the program does not recognise it and ends up on the else state. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter amount of money followed by the currency name:" 
        + "y for yen, p for pound or e for euro, like 3.40e. \n"
        << "This app will convert it to dollars. \n";
    double amount;
    char currency = ' ';
    double dollars;
    cin >> amount >> currency;

    cout<<"amount:  "<< amount <<"\n";
    cout<<"currency :" << currency<<"\n";

    if (currency == 'y'){
        cout <<amount<<"Yuan = "<< amount * 0.15<<" dollars";
    }
    else if (currency == 'e') {
        cout << amount << "Euro = " << amount * 1.18 << " dollars";
    }
    else if (currency == 'p') {
        cout << amount << "Pounds = " << amount * 1.29<< " dollars";
    }
    else {
        dollars = 0;
        cout << "Unknown currency\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`operator >>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) reads elements separated by whitespace (or until an unparseable character).

`6e` cannot be parsed as a `double` (but `e` is a valid character for scientific notation, so it is consumed), and `cin` goes into a failed state and every subsequent `>>` call fails.

For `cin >> amount >> currency;` to work the input should look like `6 e` (or `6e0e`).

If you want `6e` to also work as an input, you'd need to read it as a string (or read the entire line with [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)) and parse it yourself (e.g. extract and the suffix character, then parse the remaining digits as a `double`).

See also this similar question: [Read float from input stream without the “E”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631011/read-float-from-input-stream-without-leading-e).

Comment: Please also be aware that `6f` represents the float nearest to 6. Thus, Reading and validating the user input string is what I recommend.